# Force ubuntu to use igb driver on interface

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, ethernet

Is there any way to force an interface to use a specific driver?

I'm using Ubuntu.
I've got 6 Interfaces, some use tg3, some igb driver.
I need to use igb on eht4, but how could i make that work?

Thanks

Comment: What is the manufacturer and model (and PCI VID:PID from lspci -tvnn) of eth4? What driver does it currently use?

Comment: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1657]
It currently uses tg3

Comment: And why do you want to use igb for it? You have a Broadcom device and the driver is for Intel devices.

Comment: I use a specific Security Product hosted on the server which needs to use the driver for a specific interface.